# How do I tell if I'm good friends with someone?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm really stuck on this. I talk to scoot and send him gifts but when it came to valentines day, he didn't send me a chocolate heart. Which is what I really so desperately want!

Answer (score 4):

When you're good friends with a villager, they will tend to give you lots of presents. They will offer to sell you something of theirs and to buy some of the items you hold in your pockets, such as furniture and clothing items. They will frequently ask for favors.

Another thing that close villagers will do is visit your home. If you're in your house for a while, whether you're reorganizing your rooms or you're just sitting there, villagers will often stop by for a visit.

Once you've become super close with them, they will often give you their picture. Each picture has the date of their birth and their favorite quote. You can display them in your home, and they give tons of points for your HHA score. Sometimes, if a villager is moving away, they will send you their picture via mail the day they leave.

There are lots of ways to get a villager to warm up to you, and if these things happen to you then you know you're doing it right.

Comment: This answer explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

They will invite you to their house and possibly give you their picture. They will also start asking for names to call you and little 'secret names' (Papi asked me to come up with a secret code name)...

Answer (score 0):

The only real landmark of friendship on Animal Crossing New Leaf is when they send you their picture. 
There are no trackers for your progress I'm afraid.